# Recorrer n columnas de un archivo excel y pasarlo a una lista en python

Tags: python, excel, anaconda

[image: Mi archivo a recorrer CONECTIVIDAD-2125-TDRP.xlsx]

> > Deseo recorrer todas las columnas de mi archivo excel y copiarle a una lista, incluyendo toda la información que contenga y luego la lista pasar a copiar a un nuevo archivo excel, el excel de salida debe ser igual a la imagen, claro antes tengo que verificar si entre los dos archivos excel son iguales en una determinada columna, y copiar todos los registros que son iguales a un nuevo archivo excel, he agregado está línea de código pero no funciona **shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0),shet_comparado.cell_value(j,k)**, pero me copia solo las dos primeras columnas y antes copia otros registros, ayuda por favor.

Adjunto mi código

```
path_comparar="D:/BU/base/CONECTIVIDAD-2125-TDRP.xlsx"
file_base=xlrd.open_workbook(path_base) 
file_comparado=xlrd.open_workbook(path_comparar) 
#file_resultado=xlrd.open_workbook(path_resultado) 

shet_base=file_base.sheet_by_name("final")
shet_comparado=file_comparado.sheet_by_name("CONECTIVIDAD")
#shet_resultado=file_resultado.sheet_by_name("Hoja1")
#print(shet_comparado.nrows)
#print(shet_base.ncols)

listad = []
count=0
for i in range(shet_base.nrows):
    for j in range(shet_comparado.nrows):
        if  shet_base.cell_value(i,0)== shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0):
             count=count+1
             for k in range(shet_comparado.ncols):
                 r = **shet_comparado.cell_value(j,0),shet_comparado.cell_value(j,k)**            
                 listad.append(r)
                 
        
df = pd.DataFrame(listad)
df.columns = ['Cedula','Nombres Apellidos']
df.to_excel(excel_writer =path_resultado)
print('\n', 'Cantidad:', count)
```

[image: Archivo de salida]

Comment: Pregunta: ¿lo que quieres en la lista es el nombre de las columnas, o toda la información de las columnas, incluyendo el nombre? Por otro lado, crees que nos pudieras poner aunque sea un fragmento del archivo input y como esperarías tu output.

Answer (score 1):

Entendiendo la última edición y con la precisión que hiciste. Creo que entonces el código que necesitas sería algo así:

```
import pandas as pd

archivo = pd.read_excel("columnas.xlsx")

lista = []
columnas = archivo.columns
columnas = columnas.tolist()
valores = archivo.values
for columna in archivo:
    lista.append(columna)
    val = archivo[columna]
    for elemento in val:
        lista.append(elemento)

df = pd.DataFrame(lista)
output = df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

El excel de salida, seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Saludos!

Comment: Si, pero las columnas deben estar en forma horizontal.